# Cannot connect to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssms

I am trying to create a AWS RDS Sql Server database and connect to it from a local machine using SSMS. Later I'll be connecting from a web application (locally, then hosted somewhere eventually.) I am currently failing to connect to my instance (the instance is configured and running.) The error I'm getting is the network/instance related (not login.) Tried telnet and I can't even hit it that way.
Looking on the web, there seems to be a setup for network connections but it talks about EC2, VPC and things I don't think I need (or do I?)

Tried (nothing worked so far): Using the IP instead of hostname, explicitly specifying the port (1433), changing user/password, crying.

Speaking of things I hope I don't need to configure, there's also IAM authentication - didn't touch that yet.

Any input is appreciated before I open a ticket with Amazon.

UPDATE:

My scenario: [Scenario](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html#USER_VPC.Scenario4)

Solution - add the Inbound Rule to default Security Group: [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the configuration of the Security Group that is associated with the Amazon RDS database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with RDS, you need to set inbound rules; otherwise, you are unable to connect to the database. This concept is covered in this AWS tutorial. In this AWS tutorial, the database is MySQL and the app is a Java web app. However, the same concepts apply with respect to inbound rules:

[Creating the Amazon Relational Database Service item tracker](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/Creating_rds_item_tracker)

One tip -- when you set an inbound rule to let your development machine connect, you can select MyIP...

[image]

Also - when you host your app (for example Elastic Beanstalk), you need to set an inbound rule for that as well (as discussed in that tutorial)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I had to add the client explicitly to the security group. Everything else was created by default (VPC, SG...) when I originally created the DB. Appreciated!